# PHP memory usage goes up 50mb but result set is only ~7mb

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-management

I've stumbles upon some interesting memory things concerning PHP
Consider this code (sql-result is around 18000 rows)

```
echo memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL;

echo 'Querying mysql' . PHP_EOL;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

echo memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Size of result set' . PHP_EOL;
echo strlen(serialize($result)) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
33309232
Querying mysql
86203976

Size of result set
6838278
```

Why does the memory usage peak like this? Isn't it a little weird?

And maybe the most important question, is there something I can do to lower the usage?

Comment: Size of the result set is not 6,838,278.... that is the size of the __serialized__ result set. Don't compare chalk with cheese

Comment: You can limit your result and not fetch all 18000 rows at once. Other than that, you can try to debug Wordpress' database wrapper and figure out where it leaks memory, though there is a significant chance the leak would be in PHP itself.

Comment: Surprise, PHP has some internal overhead...!

Comment: @MarkBaker Someone else on Stack Overflow said that was a good idea to measure sizes, but apparently not.

Comment: @lanzz Ok. I'll probably have to try something else then

Comment: @Emil - it isn't a bad idea, but you need to be comparing like with like for it to have any meaning... comparing serialized data with unserialized data is not comparing like with like, same as comparing serialized data with json encoded data

Comment: @deceze ~7x is a bit too much to shrug off as "internal overhead", even considering he's comparing a `serialize()` representation against the actual memory usage. My bet is on leaks and/or stupid caching in WP's libs.

Answer (score 0):

Each row of your database is packaged into an object/hash, each value gets a hash key and the value itself, so this creates a lot of overhead.

What you can do to reduce overhead:
1) be sure to select only the columns you really need, do not just do `select *`

2)  `get_results()` has second parameter which you use to control what you get back. If you use `ARRAY_N` , you get the result as array of arrays, this should have the smallest overhead.

[wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results)

3) if this not enough, you need to get the data in batches, for example of 1000 rows.
You can use sql modifiers `offset` and `limit` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Only a basic profiling with xdebug can pinpoint the real memory usage.

Without profiling, and with bold guessing, you have multiple options :

- **paginate** your results, that is send multiple queries instead of one big
- Use **ARRAY_N** as an output format for `$wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_N)`, lighter and more compact format

**Bonus** (as Meier said) : check that you need each and every field in SELECT clause, and no `select *`

Hope this helps !